# How do I fill a combobox depending on the selection of another?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I open a modal dialog showing two combo boxes. The first one is filled with a list by code. Whenenver the user selects an entry, the second combo box needs to change its underlying list. For example: the first box shows all webcams attached to the computer and the second box shows the available resolution/streaming capabilities of the selected webcam.

This one is done with System.Windows.Forms but what's the best way to do this in Wpf and XAML?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `ItemsSource` of the first combo box to a list of available cameras. The objects should have a property of available resolutions. Bind the `SelectedItem` to a property of the view model. Then you can bind the `ItemsSource` property of the second combobox to `SelectedCamera.AvailableResolutions` or similar.

Comment: I tried your idea, but the second box remains empty. Do I need to throw some event once the selection of the first box was changed and the selected value has been written back into my property of the view model?

Comment: I made a spelling mistake. Now it works, thanks. Any idea how you make the combobox auto-select the first entry?

Comment: In the setter of the `AvailableCameras` set `SelectedCamera` to the first element if it exists.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. Another way, that I figured out, is setting the SelectedIndex to 0 in XAML. Then the combobox tries to auto-select the first entry automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete code example for anybody else to learn from. First the XAML and below the code-behind.

```
<Window x:Class="CameraSelection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:CameraSelection"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">Camera</TextBlock>
        <!-- 
        bind the source to MainWindow.Cameras; 
        set value onto MainWindow.Camera; 
        set the display member;
        auto-select first entry 
        -->
        <ComboBox Name="comboCameras" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Camera, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyNamespace:MainWindow}}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cameras, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyNamespace:MainWindow}}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">Resolution</TextBlock>
        <!-- 
        bind the source to MainWindow.Resolutions; 
        set value onto MainWindow.Resolution;
        auto-select first entry;
        reload data according to MainWindow.PropertyChanged
        -->
        <ComboBox Name="comboResolutions" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Resolution, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyNamespace:MainWindow}}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resolutions, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyNamespace:MainWindow}}" 
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  />
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Camera camera;

    #region Setters for SelectedItem

    public Camera Camera 
    {
        get { return camera; }
        set
        {
            if (value == camera)
                return;

            camera = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Camera");            // camera has changed
            OnPropertyChanged("Resolutions");       // available resolution might have changed too
        }
    }

    public Size Resolution
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ItemSources

    public IEnumerable<Camera> Cameras
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new Camera { Name = "Integrated Webcam", Resolutions = new[] { new Size(800,600), new Size(640,480) } };
            yield return new Camera { Name = "USB Webcam", Resolutions = new[] { new Size(1024, 768), new Size(800, 600) } };
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Size> Resolutions
    {
        get
        {
            if (Camera == null)
                yield break;

            foreach (Size resolution in camera.Resolutions)
                yield return resolution;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Camera
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Size> Resolutions 
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```